# Regex to parse address house and apartment numbers

Tags: c#, regex

currently I'm using this regex

```
private string DigExp = @"[^\d]";
```

that way:

```
Regex.Match(Address, DigExp, "")
```

while string address usually containes characters and numbers..
let's say if address is
"ipsum lorem 30/9" or "ipsum lorem 309" i still get 309 as result in both examples. i need two regex to solve it, one to match first number until the / if exist at all, and another one to match the second that should be after / at the end of the string and may not exist at all.

I need address numbers seperated into regex groups withous the /

can you please guide me to achieve my goal?
thanks.

Comment: Why replace? You can match these numbers with a single *match* with the [`(\d+)(?:/(\d+))?`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5cd%2b)(%3f%3a%2f(%5cd%2b))%3f&i=ipsum+lorem+30%2f9%0d%0a%0d%0aipsum+lorem+309) pattern.

Comment: well i need the extracted values as function return, calling it seperately from distinct places. can you please split your regex, I don't really understand how it works to split it myself..

Comment: FYI `\D` is the same thing as `[^\d]`

Comment: Will there always be just 1 set of `XX/YY` per string?

Comment: no. sometimes it won't have any numbers at all... can't be: "lorem ipsumdfsdfdsfdfsdfdsf" , "lorem ipsum 2312" , "lorem ipsum 333/" , "lorem ipsum 231233/4" and even sometimes "lorem ipsum /4546234" .... must have two regex, one to get the first if exist, and another one to get the second number...

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/topics](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/topics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using groups, you can use the following regex to isolate the different parts of the address string. The following separates the address into the all of the words, and the numbers before and after the optional slash:

```
((?:[a-zA-Z]+\s)*)([\d]+)(?:(?:\/)(\d+))?
```

e.g: `"ipsum lorem 30/9"` becomes:

> **Match #0**  Length: 16  Range: 1-16
>
> ipsum lorem 30/9
>
> **Group #1**  Length: 12
>
> ipsum lorem
>
> **Group #2**  Length: 2
>
> 30
>
> **Group #3**  Length: 1
>
> 9

*Note:* The follow regex adds the ability to match words after the numbers in a fourth group:

((?:[a-zA-Z]+\s)*)([\d]+)(?:(?:/)(\d+))?((?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)*)

Comment: looks the same, sure?

Comment: @k-man Sorry, not sure how that happened, haha. Also, do you need the slash included in the return value?

Comment: string firstExp = @"(\d+)(?:\/\d+)";
string secondExp = @"(?:\/)(\d+)";
string address = "שדרות יעלים 30/9";
string houseNum = Regex.Replace(address, firstExp, "");
string aptNum = Regex.Replace(address, secondExp, "");

Comment: with the first i get the characters and not any number, with the second i get characters with first number... and no / shouldn't be part of results

Comment: @k-man I'm still having difficulty understanding you, what exactly do you want? With your current use of replace, you will erase whatever is matched. I designed my patterns to return the respective numbers as the first group, but this doesn't seem to be what you want? how exactly are you implementing this?

Comment: @k-man, sorry, a lot of questions there. First, are you trying to return these strings that are matched, to edit `address` in relation to the numbers?

Comment: yeah afcourse, i need address to be splitted to all it's components... ok so now i understand what groups are, I'll use Regex.Match function.. can you please update your answer and write your patter to get those numbers in Match Groups? tnx

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get those in two groups:

```
(\d+)/?(\d*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use this pattern:

```
([\d\/\d]+|\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `[a-zA-Z\s]*([\d]*)\/?([\d]*)?`. That will get the first part in the first group and anything after the `/` in the second group.

Comment: must have it in two diffrent calls, can you write your answer as two seperated regex?